# "No transactional EntityManager available" with Spring 4, HIbernate 3 in a TestNG test case

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-orm

I looked at various blogs about this, but I am getting the below exception no matter what I try.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:273)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.genericdao.dao.jpa.JPABaseDAO._persist(JPABaseDAO.java:99)
    at com.googlecode.genericdao.dao.jpa.JPABaseDAO._persistOrMerge(JPABaseDAO.java:265)
    at com.googlecode.genericdao.dao.jpa.GenericDAOImpl.save(GenericDAOImpl.java:113)
    at com.test.dao.shared.CompanyDAOImpl.create(CompanyDAOImpl.java:17)
    ... 27 more
```

Below is my spring xml

**dao/spring/test-mysqldb-applicationContext.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan
        base-package="com.test.dao.shared,
        com.test.dao" />


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="blacksmithDS"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blacksmithtestdb" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="blacksmithDS" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.beans" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">test</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">test</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
    </bean>

            <bean id="sharedTransactionTemplate"
            class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
            <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
            <property name="timeout" value="30" />
            <property name="propagationBehavior" value="3" /> <!--requires_new -->
        </bean>

        <bean id="metadataUtil"
            class="com.googlecode.genericdao.search.jpa.hibernate.HibernateMetadataUtil"
            factory-method="getInstanceForEntityManagerFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="searchProcessor" class="com.googlecode.genericdao.search.jpa.JPASearchProcessor">
            <constructor-arg ref="metadataUtil" />
        </bean>

</beans>
```

Please find the TestNG Test Case below

```
public class DAOBaseTest  {

    protected static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    protected static SharedObjectDAO<Company,Long>  companyDAO;
    private static final AtomicInteger sCounter = new AtomicInteger();


    @BeforeSuite
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"classpath:dao/spring/test-mysqldb-applicationContext.xml"});

        companyDAO = (SharedObjectDAO) applicationContext.getBean("companyDAO");
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional (value="transactionManager")
    public void testCompanyCreate() throws Exception {

        Company c = new Company();
        c.setName("Test Company " + sCounter.incrementAndGet());
        c.setWebsite("www.testing.com");

        companyDAO.create(c);

    }

}
```

DAOs below

**SharedObjectDAO.java**

```
public interface SharedObjectDAO<DO extends ACreationDatedEntity, ID extends Serializable> extends GenericDAO<DO,ID> {

    public DO create(DO dataObject) throws YAPPersistException;
}
```

**CompanyDAOImpl.java**

```
@Repository ("companyDAO")
public class CompanyDAOImpl extends BaseDAO<Company, Long> implements SharedObjectDAO<Company, Long> {

    public Company create(Company companyDO) throws YAPPersistException {

        try {
            companyDO = save(companyDO);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new YAPPersistException(ex);
        }

        return companyDO;

    }
}
```

**BaseDAO.java**

```
@Repository ("baseDAO")
public class BaseDAO<DO extends ACreationDatedEntity, ID extends Serializable> extends GenericDAOImpl<DO,ID> { 

    @Override
    @Autowired
    @PersistenceContext
    @Qualifier(value = "entityManagerFactory")
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super.setEntityManager(entityManager);
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "searchProcessor")
    public void setSearchProcessor(JPASearchProcessor searchProcessor) {
        super.setSearchProcessor(searchProcessor);
    }

}
```

Below is the pom dependencies and versions

**pom.xml**

```
   <properties>
            <log4j2.version>2.3</log4j2.version>
            <hikaricp.version>2.4.1</hikaricp.version>
            <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
            <spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
            <jersey.version>2.9</jersey.version>
            <jackson.version>2.4.3</jackson.version>
            <hibernate.version>3.6.10.Final</hibernate.version>
            <genericdao.version>1.1.0</genericdao.version>
            <jsonassert.version>1.2.3</jsonassert.version>
            <hsqldb.version>2.2.8</hsqldb.version>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-entity-filtering</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.182</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Google apis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.genericdao</groupId>
        <artifactId>dao-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${genericdao.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.genericdao</groupId>
        <artifactId>search-jpa-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${genericdao.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>${hikaricp.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
    <version>${jsonassert.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT - Fixed Test Case**

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:dao/spring/test-mysqldb-applicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional
public class DAOBaseTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    protected SharedObjectDAO<Company, Long> companyDAO;
    private static final AtomicInteger sCounter = new AtomicInteger();


    @Test
    public void testCompanyCreate() throws Exception {

        Company c = new Company();
        c.setName("Test Company " + sCounter.incrementAndGet());
        c.setWebsite("www.testing.com");

        companyDAO.create(c);

    }

}
```

So to summarize, my issue got fixed after changing the static autowired bean dependencies in test to non static after extending from AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests

Comment: Ofcourse not. You have `@Transactional` on a test method, this test method is on a class that isn't a spring bean so no transaction is started. Use one of the TestNG base classes from Spring and cleanup your testcode with it.

Comment: Hi Deinum, Thanks for the response. I had also tried with extending AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests in my tests case. But I had done a mistake. I had the autowired spring bean references in the test class as static and the insert was not happening. When I changed that it works fine now. I have refactored the test case to avoid static bean references.